# Printing Graphic In WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a class the creates return a `Graphics`. I want to print this graphic in my main form. How ever `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArg.Graphics` is read only. How do I print my `Graphics` with out being able to set `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArg.Graphics`

```
    public Graphics makeLabel()
    {

        Graphics label = Graphics.FromImage(makeBitMap());
        label.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
        label.DrawImage(Barcode,1, 200);
        label.DrawString("Do Not Seperate", makeFont(), Brushes.Black, 100, 2);
        label.DrawString("Choking Hazard", makeFont(), Brushes.Black, 200, 2);
        return label;

    }
```

Comment: A graphics object refers to an object that capable of being drawn on.  Could be a window or a bitmap.  Or the printer.  The only way to get one for the printer is from the PrintDocument.PrintPage event.  It is entirely unclear what that class returns.  But surely not a Graphics object that draws to the printer.

Comment: @matzone I am using the PrintDocument but print using PrintDocument you need to use System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics but you can't set it only get it.

Comment: @HansPassant I have attached my method that returns the Graphics object. So there is no way to keep it out of that Form class?

Comment: Return the bitmap, not the Graphics.